# How to load a html page in webview (windows phone) using c sharp

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, webview

I am developing an e-book project in Windows phone, I am struggling to load a HTML page in webview which is downloaded in local folder. How can I open a local HTML file which is saved in Local folder.
The below is the code that I have tried so far.

```
string url = "ms-appdata:///Local//Downloaded//ebook//index.html";
MyWebView.Navigate ( new Uri(url) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the file and store content in a string variable and use that string content as follows:

MyWebView.NavigateToString(content );